# Kafka Topic Compaction - Tombstone not getting deleted and kafka is preserving last two records for the key

Tags: apache-kafka

I created a topic with the following configs -

```
min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.01
cleanup.policy=compact
segment.ms=100
delete.retention.ms=100
```

After certain messages I pushed to kafka, I found that my kafka always returns me last two entries for a key and when I push a null value for a key, tombstone is not getting deleted.

Am I missing any config here.

I waS expecting only the last record for a key and the tombstones to be deleted quickly as my delete.retention.ms is 100.

Comment: Push null value using what? Consuming how? KTable should be used to check keys, not consuming direct from topic... Also, tombstones shouldn't be deleted since that is "the last key"

Comment: @OneCricketeer, pushing data using my application to kafka topic. Eg. 111:null. Note- null is not in string format. 
Consuming the msg in local terminal of mac. --> `./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092   --topic auto-instance-delete --from-beginning --property print.key=true`

Yes, tombstone is my last value of the key. 
I didn’t understand this --> "Also, tombstones shouldn't be deleted since that is "the last key""

Answer (score 0):

It won't be removed (and will still be consumable) from the topic, until compaction.

The head segments of any Kafka topic-partition always have all records sent (and therefore consumable) so will contain all keys and values (including nulls) most recently sent

If you want to have key lookups from compacted topics, you need to query a KTable instead of using consumer API